# apply using multi-column data to produce a single numeric output

Tags: r

Is it possible to use some form of an array and send it to apply on a row-by-row basis? Everything I've tried so far results in the error "incorrect number of dimensions" which is a common error others have had here but I cannot find and example of how to do what I'm attempting to do in TestFunc2 below.

```
require(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY",src="yahoo")

nData = 10
data = ClCl(SPY)[1:nData,]

TestFunc1 = function(d1, x1, y1){
  res1 = (d1 + 2*x1)^2 + y1
}

#X1 is a constant - this works
X1 = .2
Y1 = 1
tmp1 = apply(data, 1, TestFunc1, X1, Y1)
Result1 = cbind(data, X1, Y1, tmp2)



TestFunc2 = function(z1, y1){
  d1 = z1[,1]
  x1 = z1[,2]
  res2 = (d1 + 2*x1)^2 + y1
}

X2 = xts(1:nData, order.by=index(data))
Z1 = cbind(data, X2)
tmp2 = apply(Z1, 1, TestFunc2, Y1)

Result2 = cbind(data, X2, Y1, tmp2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is the way that you treat `z1` in `TestFunc2`.  `apply` passes each row of `Z1` into `z1` of `TestFunc2` as a *vector*, not as a data.frame.  To fix it define `TestFunc2` as:

```
TestFunc2 = function(z1, y1){
  d1 = z1[1]
  x1 = z1[2]
  res2 = (d1 + 2*x1)^2 + y1
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher. It does work but I sure didn't see that reading the help page on apply. I appreciate the help.